# Does anyone know how to activate a MuJoCo license key? I cannot find the proper directories/files even though I definitely have them

Tags: python, terminal, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I cannot find the directory ~/mjpro200/bin or ~/mjpro200/model and thus I cannot test my activation key or run a test simulation. MuJoCo is successfully installed on my VMware Ubuntu 18.04 virtual machine so I believe I should be able to find the files but I cannot. If anyone could help they would be a godsend. I have spent so long troubleshooting with MuJoCo.